# Global solution for Lotka-Voltera like system of ODEs.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the system
$$
\begin{cases}
u'(t) &= u(t) - au^2(t) - u(t)v(t), \\
v'(t) &= -bv(t) + u(t)v(t), \\
u(0) &= u_0, \\
v(0) &= v_0.
\end{cases}
\;\text{with}\; u_0,v_0,a,b > 0
$$
of ordinary differential equations. How can I show that there exists a solution $y(t) = (u(t), v(t))$ with $t \in [0, \infty)$?

I was able to show uniqueness with Picard-Lindelöf theorem. I also presume that it should be sufficient to show that $y$ is bounded everywhere.